# Class declaration without private or public at the beginning

Tags: java

Why there is a Java class declaration without public or private at the beginning?

For example :

```
class MyClass{
  // code 
}
```

Comment: because it is default... means a class declaration without public or private is always private.

Comment: @StefanBeike Actually, in Java, the lack of modifier is not equivalent to private as indicated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497

Answer (score 3):

It is called default access modifier or package private modifier. It means that class is accessible only within the package it is in.